# How do I print the highest of an inputted value from an array, which has the same highest value? In Python 3

Tags: python

I hope this question makes sense because I'm not too sure how to ask it.

But my program - in python - asks the user to input their score from 1-10 on these ice cream flavours in an array. Displays their score and then prints their highest score as their favourite flavour. Which takes the number of index and prints that flavour from the array. However, let's say if the user put Mint Choc Chip and Strawberry both as 10. The program will only print the item that is in the array first, which is min choc chip despite strawberry also being the highest score. Does anyone know a way which can make the program display all the highest scored flavours? Please keep in mind that I am new to Python so if the answer seems obvious to you, it is not for me. So please be kind and any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

**I have tried** to add this: *if high > 1:
  print ("\nYour favourite flavour of ice cream is", flavours[high], flavours[high])*

But just prints the same flavour that appears in the array twice, so it will print: Your favourite flavour of ice cream is mint choc chip mint choc chip. And I know this doesn't make sense because if the highest score was three flavours it will only print two (of the same). I have also tried to look for other functions such as import etc. But I couldn't find one that helps. This is not necessary for the program but will make it better and more realistic. Thank you!

code:

```
import numpy as np

flavours = ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Mint Choc Chip", "Rosewater", "Strawberry", "Mango", "Frutti Tutti", "Fudge Brownie", "Bubblegum", "Stracciatella"]

Ice_Cream= [0]*10

print("Please input your score on these flavours of ice cream. With 1 being the lowest and 10 the highest.\n")

for i in range(0,10):
    print(flavours[i]+":")
    Ice_Cream[i] = int(input())

print("\nResults:\n")

for i in range(0,10):
      print(flavours[i]+":",Ice_Cream[i])

high = np.argmax(Ice_Cream)

if high > 1:
  print ("\nYour favourite flavour of ice cream is", flavours[high], flavours[high])

else:

  print ("\nYour favourite flavour of ice cream is", flavours[high])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
high=[i for i, x in enumerate(Ice_Cream) if x == max(Ice_Cream)]
for i in high:
  print ("Your favourite flavour of ice cream is", flavours[i])
```

variable high stores all the indices of max values of icecreams

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy.argmax returns an *array* of indices of maximum values https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html.

You should iterate through it

```
for i in np.nditer(high):
    print ("\nYour favourite flavour of ice cream is", flavours[i])
```